# making a sequence to converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}=a_n-(a_n)^2$
determine the value of $a_0$ thak makes 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

the book says that the answer is $a_0\in[0,1]$

I tried to find $a_n$ in terms of n but failed. Is this approach correct or are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_n-a_{n+1}=a_n^2\ge 0$, so the sequence is decreasing. This proves that $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

On the other hand, if for some $n$ we have $a_n>1$ then $a_{n+1}<0$ so $a_n\le 1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

If $a_n=0$ for some $n$ then all the following terms are $0$. The same if $a_1=1$.

Otherwise, dividing by $a_n$ we get
$$0<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1-a_n<1-a_1<1$$
so $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Hem, this proves $a_n$ positive: $2\to-2\to-6\to\cdots$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In the second line I prove that, given that the sequence converges to $0$, your example is discarded.

Comment: As written, your text is wrong.

Comment: I really don't understand

Comment: $a_n-a_{n+1}=a_n^2$ does *not* prove $a_n\ge0$.

Comment: If the sequence is decreasing and it converges to $0$, every term is non-negative

Comment: Right, but you didn't say that. You've been here long enough to know how to present an argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93474/discussion-between-ajotatxe-and-yves-daoust).